# node.js crypto: sign a hash value

Tags: node.js, hash, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

node.js has a built in crypto libraray to do RSA signining:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
var sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256')
sign.update('my plaintext')
var privateKey = getPrivateKeySomehow()
console.log(sign.sign(privateKey, 'hex'))
```

But what, if the process of signature creation should be devided in an instance hashing the the plaintext, and a seperated instance signing the hash value. This is quite usual with hardware (smartcard) or remote signature (HSM, Key Vault).

At the moment I use the node-forge module. But I would prefer node.js crypto, if I knew how...

Comment: It should work with `crypto.privateEncrypt` and `crypto.publicDecrypt`, but it [doesn't](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/57c494411ea45251499c65f9fe202079) for some reason.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Probably uses PKCS#1 padding for encryption / decryption instead of signature generation. More information [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/1172)

Comment: Only three good cryptography related questions per day allowed, user1875068 :P

Comment: @Maarten I've upvoted both question and answer back in 2014 ;) I see that the decrypted signature is ASN.1 encoded and the included hash matches. It would probably be too much hassle for this use case.

Comment: Could you try if just a single `createSign("RSA")` works? You could give that the ASN.1 encoded hash.

Comment: @ArtjomB. your example nearly works, the ASN.1 stuff is just a prefix that you need to add to the digest before doing the RSA operation (and strip of before comparing hashes), you don’t need to have a full ASN.1 processor. Have a look at [my fork of your gist](https://gist.github.com/mattwildig/33e9e7d6b4561f0db5283afe1a9eeb94). As an example, the [Go std lib also does this the same way with precalculated ASN.1 prefixes for the different hash functions](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/83843b16100d889bc84580c9427e02c7c9cee769/src/crypto/rsa/pkcs1v15.go#L196-L213).

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks a lot, that was the perfect approach

Comment: @matt and that the perfect solution - even verification works!